# Creating RelayCommand without implementing ICommand

Tags: c#, mvvm, relaycommand

My query is how can I create a class behaving same as RelayCommand but without implementing ICommand for my MVVM application? Any suggestions are much appreciated.

My RelayCommand [which implements ICommand] is as below:

```
 public class RelayCommand:ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> m_Execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> m_CanExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> exec) : this(exec, null) { }
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> exec, Predicate<object> canExec)
        {
            if (exec == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("exec");

            m_Execute = exec;
            m_CanExecute = canExec;
        }

        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter == null)
                return true;
            else
                return m_CanExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                if (m_CanExecute != null)
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                if (m_CanExecute != null)
                    CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            m_Execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: What is your motivation to do so?

Comment: I have no motivation for me. I was asked to implement it in one of my interview, when I shown him my above RelayCommand implementation. So, it is troubling me.

Comment: Just remove `: ICommand` from your code and it won't implement it anymore... But it's pointless.

Comment: @Guillaume: I am sorry. My RelayCommand is standalone but it is getting used by my ViewModel. If I remove ICommand, my code will not be compiled.  I want my application compiled but RelayCommand implementation without ICommand.

Comment: Perhaps follow up with your interviewer about what they meant and wanted to achieve - asking a question about the interview afterwards can be a positive sign.

Comment: It's too late. I can't do it now ;)

Comment: If your RelayCommand doesn't implement ICommand, then it can't be used for the Command properties on buttons / menus, which defeats the purpose of using a command at all. Maybe the interviewer meant *without using commands*? In that case, you would call the "execute" in a `Click` event handler, and bind a "can execute" property to `IsEnabled`.